# Drag-and-drop file upload component

Tags: html, css, react.js, jsx

I've tried to make a custom file upload input. The goal was to just have a nicer looking file input compared to its unaltered version.

One thing I don't like is the CSS. I don't like altering the position, but maybe that is just how it has to be? (Since the input and input button are hidden from view. It was a bit difficult to get the items lined up properly without using top, bottom, margin, etc.

Typically I just try to stick to only using flexbox if possible. But having the input set to absolute messed up the flow.

Also, if there are any other suggestions on how to make this better, they would be appreciated!

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from '../Button';
import './FileUpload.scss';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

const FileUpload = ({ changed }) => {
  const [selectedFileName, setSelectedFileName] = useState('');
  const [fileIsHoveringInput, setFileIsHoveringInput] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const input = document.getElementById('file-input');
    if (input) {
      input.addEventListener('drop', drop);
      input.addEventListener('dragenter', dragenter);
      input.addEventListener('dragleave', dragleave);
    }
  });

  const drop = () => {
    setFileIsHoveringInput(false);
  };

  const dragenter = () => {
    setFileIsHoveringInput(true);
  };

  const dragleave = () => {
    setFileIsHoveringInput(false);
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = onloadEvent => {
      const content = onloadEvent.target.result;
      const workBook = XLSX.read(content, { type: 'binary' });
      const sheet = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      const workSheet = workBook.Sheets[sheet];
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, { header: 1 });
      setSelectedFileName(file.name);
      changed(data);
    };

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  };

  const determineLabelToUse = () => {
    if (selectedFileName) {
      return selectedFileName;
    } else {
      return 'Drag & drop file, or';
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`file-upload ${fileIsHoveringInput ? 'hover' : ''}`}>
        <input
          type='file'
          id='file-input'
          name='image_uploads'
          accept='.xls, .xlsx, .csv'
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <div className='icon-container'>
          <div className='icon' data-icon='upload' />
        </div>
        <label htmlFor='file-input'>{determineLabelToUse()}</label>
        <Button
          id='secondary-button'
          type='secondary'
          disabled={fileIsHoveringInput}
        >
          {selectedFileName ? 'Replace File' : 'Choose File'}
        </Button>
        <p>(.xls, .xlsx, .csv)</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;
```

Here is the stylesheet:

```
@mixin core-rules {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #acabab;

  :hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  label {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  p {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  #secondary-button {
    position: relative;
    top: 21px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .-oneX-icon {
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 15px;
  }
}

.file-upload {
  @include core-rules;
}

.file-upload.hover {
  @include core-rules;
  border: 2px dashed #acabab;
}
```

The resulting appearance on my system:

[image: Screenshot of file component]